# How to connect to AD-LDS without sending passwords in plaintext?

Tags: ldap, ad-lds, adam

I created an AD-LDS instance using the Administrative Tools Active Directory Lightweight Directory Services Setup Wizard.

I can connect to the instance with ldp.exe on localhost:389.

However, I can only Bind to the server using the Simple Bind option.  This sends the password in plaintext.

All other options return an error of "Invalid Credentials".

**How can I make a connection to AD-LDS to validate user/password credentials without sending it in plaintext?**

Answer (score 4):

You can configure SSL and do a bind over 3389.
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc731012(v=ws.10)